# Since SQL Server doesn't have packages, what do programmers do to get around it?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, package

I have a SQL Server database that has a huge proliferation of stored procedures. Large numbers of stored procedures are not a problem in my Oracle databases because of the Oracle "package" feature.

What do programmers do to get around the lack of a "package" feature like that of Oracle?

Comment: I personally thank you for asking this question.  As others have clearly noticed... this is an emotional topic.  Working in SQL Server now for 2 years after working in Oracle for 8 years... not having packages is a hinderance.  But... SQL Server has some awesome features like just being able to write standard SQL on the page and set variables and the ability to update data using a multi-joined query.  Oracle and Microsoft just need to sit down at a table together... take their best features and create a beautiful database system.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

While SQL Server has nothing to offer by way of the "cool features" of encapsulation and package state **like you are used to**, you can organize your stored procedures into schemas.

In enterprise manager, these procs are still all listed together which makes for a HUGE treelist if you have hundreds of procs.  I too miss the organization and cool features of Oracle packages.  However, all platforms have their strengths.

NOTE: Writing stored procedures in the .NET language DOES give you encapsulation and state.  It still does not however separate them in the EM treeview in any special way.

Answer (score 15):

Come up with a good naming convention, use it, and enforce it.

Answer (score 8):

Schemas may be used to organize stored procedures and other objects. Personally, I prefer to use schemas when they organize objects by functional area, and where those funcational areas correspond to security boundaries. An example of this is found in the AdventureWorks sample databse, which has schemas like "HumanResources" and "Sales". The theory being that a given user may need access to objects in "HumanResources", but may not need access to "Sales" information.

An alternative is to use a naming convention and enforce it, as James says above. I'll add that SQL Server Management Studio has a filter button that can be used to filter the list of objects displayed. For instance, one can click on the "Stored Procedures" folder and filter on Name contains "Add".

On my current project, I have pulled a number of SQL queries out of SSIS packages and into stored procedures. In order to distinguish between these stored procedures and those that should be of general use, I have prefixed the names with "ssis". It would certainly have been more pleasant if I could have created something similar to a namespace in C# or C++, and created "SSIS.SelectUserLookupData" instead of "ssis_SelectUserLookupData". It would be even nicer if these namespaces could be nested.

If this is one of the featues of Packages in Oracle, then perhaps someone would let me know.

Comment: I like how you provide an answer to a question that you closed as "not a question".  Truly classy.

Comment: @Jedi: I don't see how to win with you. Once the Community decided, by reopening, that this _was_ a question, I've _treated_ it like a question, and contributed something that I don't think was previously present. If someone actually finds this question looking for help, I think my answer may help a little. It comes from my experience, as opposed to the "rewrite" we discussed and I decided against.

Comment: @John Saunders: so you actually needed other people to tell you this is a question?!  lol

Comment: @Jedi: I needed someone else to help me ignore the snobbish attitude in the original question, and hear the question the way it should have been asked.

Answer (score 8):

I've worked with both SQL Server and Oracle so have seen the good and bad of both.  As the above comments have beena bit heated I'll try and keep this as neutral as possible...

So, what's an Oracle Package?  Think of it like a database class

The Package has two elements: a header file and a body file.  The header file is your public interface, and contains the signature (name, params and return type if applicable) of all the stored procedures or functions (in Oracle a function returns a value, a stored proc doesn't) that are directly callable.  The package body must implement all the procedure signatures in the package header file.

The body element of the package contains all the stored procs and logic that actually do the work.  You may have a Save procedure declared in the package header that calls an insert or update proc that exists in the body.  The developer can only see the "Save" proc.  It's important to keep in mind that the package body can also implement procs or functions not declared in the package header, they're just not accessible outside of the package itself.

I found packages to be really useful for a number of reasons:

1. You've got the concept of a public interface that can be provided to other developers
2. Packages can mirror your compiled classes.  My Orders.Save() C# method will call my Oracle Orders.SaveLineItem method to save each line item and an Oracle SaveOrder method to save the order summary details.
3. My procs are grouped together in a nice, logical way inside the packages

Personally, I would be love MS to implement some kind of package functionality as I think it makes for a cleaner database.

Comment: I want to be able to write a Procedure on my 'page' and work with it... without compiling it.  Oracle package syntax allows for this.  I can create a Proc and a Function and immediately work with them without ever having to compile them.  Declare - Begin - End... Declare all vars, functions, procs... and then in the Begin - End... use them.. all on one page.  I very much wish Microsoft let me do this but alas... I have to compile my function into a list of 1000 other functions that have nothing to do with my work.

Answer (score 2):

One additional feature of packages that was not mentioned is the ability to 'wrap' the body.  The header is always public and can be viewed by anyone with permissions to execute the package.  But that also allows them to view the code in the body.  You can wrap the body, encrypting it, and prevent anyone from seeing what the code is actually doing.  Its a nice feature where security is a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

3) The best argument against oracle packages is that based on experience and research on the Ask Tom site, one can't update a package without taking it off line. This is unacceptable. With SQL Server, we can update stored procedures on the fly, without interrupting production operation.

I understand the frustration of this statement, but I would not call id "unacceptable". In a true production environment, changes should never be tested in production. Updates should be moved from a test environment to production in a scheduled and orderly manner. In a 24/7 system, then redundant production environment should handle down time while servers are updated. Not only does the package have to be taken off line, but the new package, if not compiled, will fail when placed back on line. There is a DBA element required for Oracle databases. However, I do miss the Oracle packages.

Comment: I've never had any issues updating a package in oracle in the manner this answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat funny to see how emotional one can get over such a dry subject.
The fact that Oracle has a feature that SQL Server does not seems to generate all kinds of reactions towards the disputable characteristics of this feature.

For starters, the question was in the style: there is this feature in Oracle that is being missed in SQL Server and what is the recommended approach.

No need to get emotional about it.

For those who do not like the packaging feature in Oracle, -for whatever the reason-, they still can go about it the same way one can do with SQL Server.

Getting more into the detail, there could be a follow-up question in the style: when modifying a function or procedure within a package, the entire package is invalidated and this "sucks", what would be the recommended way to avoid the sucking aspect.

Personally, I have never seen anyone complaining about not being able to modify a statically linked library in an executable without having to relink it.

Comment: Trust me... not bringing emotion into something that saved so much time and allowed you to organize your 'crap' in such a meaningful and useful way to all of a sudden... changing jobs and now you're stuck working with something that seems to you should have been left back in the 90s.  I thought I was just biased as I worked in Oracle for 8 years... but now that I've worked in SQL Server for 2 years... Oracle is better and yes I'm emotional about it.  I want my work life to be easier... not harder.  Time is my life... Oracle saved me time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Like people have said, Schema's are a more logical and ANSI compliant way to organize database tables and procedures.
2. Software engineering best practices are that we should never make a change directly on any server. Since all database sprocs are scripted and under configuration control, we can arrange those scripts into any folder structure we want.

(outdated info sourced from AskTom has been removed)

Comment: -1: this doesn't actually answer the question, though it comes close.

Comment: It does answer your query, because it shows that it's an invalid question. When you add a schema to your sprocs, they will be organized. Instead of dbo.my_sproc, it will be displayed as mypackage.my_sproc.  Secondly, if you script your database, you will very rarely look for sprocs on the database.

Comment: "one can't update a package without taking it off line"
These warning statements about about Oracle packages are wrong. You can use CREATE OR REPLACE statement for immediately change and compile a package body.

Comment: I've never had any issues updating a package in oracle in the manner this answer suggests.

Answer (score -2):

I would thank my lucky stars that SQL Server doesn't have packages.  Oracle packages suck.

> Hmm, we need a way to take all these procedures and put them in one place.  I know!  Let's make developers create and maintain two files for each package.  They will love us forever!

As long as MS never implements packages like Oracle did, it'll be a win in my book.

EDIT for commenters:

Oracle Packages are simply a way to organize your stored procedures into, well, packages so that you don't have 100 stored procedures sitting around, but maybe 5 packages.  They're not stackable like packages in Java or C# code.  All packages are at the same level.

A package requires two files: the headers file and the body file.  This creates frustration when adding new procedures to an existing package, because you cannot add the body without adding the header, even though it contains the exact same information as is in the body.

For example, here is a snippet from the header file of one of my packages:

```
    PROCEDURE bulk_approve_events
(
    i_last_updated_by IN VARCHAR2,
    o_event OUT NUMBER
);
```

And here's the corresponding procedure in the body:

```
    PROCEDURE bulk_approve_events
(
    i_last_updated_by IN VARCHAR2,
    o_event OUT NUMBER
) IS
...
BEGIN
...
END;
```

No difference.  The header file is useless and is simply another hurdle for the developer to step over when developing with packages.  On my project, we have a convention that all the commented documentation for each procedure goes in the header, along with the details of when it was added and by whom, but that could just as easily be included in the body.

Comment: @Puppies: Could you expound on that for those of us who don't know what packages are? It would be more helpful if you left out the emotion. If Oracle packages suck, they'll still such just as much if you describe them in a less emotional manner.

Comment: Packages don't require two files... in fact they don't require any files.  The create package statements are understood by the oracle interpreter and can be sent over any database connection.

Comment: Why distinct package headers and bodies?  Because the bodies can be implemented in other languages such as C or Java.  Additionally, the declaration is where you put the public interface.  Procedures and functions not in the public interface can't be called from outside the scope of the package.

Comment: @Mark: in my post, statement == file.  I have to go to two places to add a procedure to a package, and that's annoying and very broken IMO

Comment: "As long as MS never implements packages like Oracle did, it'll be a win in my book." -- well, if they did, at least you'd have a place to define CONSTANTS like you can in PL/SQL, so you don't have to litter your T-SQL code with hardcoded string values in a thousand places.

Comment: You got a lot wrong. Package header is like an IDL, (aka proxy) to the available functions, procedures. The "private" functions would not go into the header because they are available to the body itself not the outside world. Separating them allows for compiling header, body & anything in between in proper order. Just like in C, C++ you have header & the actual function body (code).  Sure higher generation languages keep track of function scope behind the scenes and do the dirty work for you. In strongly typed, what about self calling functions, can't compile 'em 'cause they don't exist.

Comment: Packages in Oracle is not about declaring things in two files. It is about encapsulation, 
separation and scoping. (As a bonus you can use package level variables.) 
Yes, having two declaration objects is a little burden. 
But in I my project I have more than 50 packages with more than 500 functions/procedures. I really like to know them encapsulated, and see them in the organic hierarchy in the editor.

Comment: Is this still the case in the 2019 version? Have the future versions introduced Packages?

Comment: Alas No... still no ability to encapsulate business logic into a package.  All of your functions for your Business logic to handle a certain action get compiled into the vast list of other functions that have nothing to do with what you are working on.  Encapsulating business logic is just one of many examples of why packages are so great.  For me it's the single page syntax of declaring functions and procs and other things like a cursor or variables all on one page... without compiling them and it just works.  Then if I like.. I can compile that work into an actual Package or Proc or Func.