# can we use packages in ms sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

can we use packages in ms sql server 2008...i m new to sql server ...
if yes how it can be created and used....

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770300/since-sql-server-doesnt-have-packages-what-do-programmers-do-to-get-around-it

Comment: Disagree that this is a duplicate.  He is asking IF there are packages.  The other one asks what to do about now having packages.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing somewhat similar would be a SQL-CLR assembly, e.g. C# code compiled into an assembly, hosted inside SQL.

There's no equivalent of a package for T-SQL stored functions and stored procedures in SQL Server.

What do you need that for, anyway? Granting permissions?

What you could investigate, too, are the `schemas` in SQL Server, which also help you grant or manage permissions - but it's quite a different beast from Oracle PL/SQL packages. Schemas manage collections of database objects (any of them - tables, views, stored procs and funcs).

- [Working with schemas in SQL Server 2005](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid87_gci1184503,00.html)
- [Security enhancements in SQL Server 2005 - schemas](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/authorization_2005_p1.aspx)

Marc

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the Oracle concept of a package which groups related queries etc.  If so as far as I know this concept doesn't exit in SQL Server.  Also you will get some interference when trying to Google for this from DTS packages, which are a completely different concept.

Comment: yup m taking abt oracle concept...is there any alternate sollution...

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to get from them, if you are just wanting to tidy up your project and group like things then not really - if you are trying to manage permissions then yes - roles.  Tell us what you are trying to achieve and I'm sure you will get many replies as to how its achieved in SQL Server.