# Group Stored Procedures based on Module in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have hundreds of stored procedures in my current database. I need to group it based on module. Is it possible in SQL Server 2008? If yes can any one help me on this.

Comment: Unfortunately SqlServer doesn't have the equivalent of e.g. an Oracle Package. The closest may be to use [Schemas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/770560/314291) to group procedures (and tables, views, functions etc) into logical groups.

Comment: @StuartLC Schemas are security feature, using it like this will probably lead to a permissions nightmare for the OP.

Comment: Agreed re security, although there is often a correlation between modules and security roles. The linked SO Post delves into the trade-offs. Close as duplicate?